# What other verbs can you use in the sentence "I injected medicine inside the syrup"?

Tags: vocabulary

The only definition that seems to match is the first one:

> 1. To force or drive (a fluid) into something: inject fuel into an engine cylinder; inject air into a liquid mixture.

However, that's pretty general, because it's "into something" instead of "into another liquid", so what other words would you use? I am not saying it's incorrect, but I am thinking there's a better word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When talking about physical objects, it would be unusual to talk about **injecting** one thing into an object that is in the same phase - solid, liquid or gas. Not necessarily incorrect in terms of definitions, but it does not match natural usage. It's also usually only used for **fluids** - that is, gasses and liquids. Some solids that have partial characteristics of liquids might also be injected (powders, for instance).

In fact, injecting anything into a liquid is unusual, though as in the definition you may hear about injecting a gas into a liquid.

Often, rather than injecting the fluid into a material, it is injected **into a container**. For example, injecting cream into a cream cake, jam into a doughnut, or medicine into a vein. Where one of these is common, it might mutate so that you are injecting a liquid into another liquid because it is in that container. So, I would say that it is most proper to say that you inject medicine into a vein, but people will say that it is injected into the blood.

Saying that you added something to a syrup seems to me to be a very unnatural place to use the verb *to inject*. Instead, I would use *to mix*, or if another emphasis is needed, *to conceal*.

(Also, '*inside*' is an odd choice of preposition. I would use that to talk about where the act of injecting took place, usually, but even then it's odd. It is used sometimes with *inject* in the way you are using, but generally to emphasise where the injected substance ends up - especially when it is concealed in a solid object.)

So, depending on the emphasis or the impression you want to give, I would use:

> I **mixed** medicine **into** the syrup
>   I **concealed** medicine in the syrup
>   I **added** medicine **to** the syrup

The different prepositions are used with the different verbs. I don't think you could use any of the others with *concealed*, just *in*, but *mixed* could work with *in* instead of *into*, and *added* with *into* instead of *to*. The ones above are those I consider most natural.

One final note: *injected* will usually make people think of it being done with a **syringe**, if that makes sense in the specific case. As such, some people use the word specifically to suggest the use of a syringe. However, that can't make the word work in all situations. If you were using a syringe, you can indicate that explicitly:

> I added medicine to the syrup **with a syringe**